# Saving FileSystemInfo Array to File

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, file, serialization

I'm attempting to save an array of FileInfo and DirectoryInfo objects for use as a log file.  The goal is to capture an image of a directory (and subdirectories) at a point in time for later comparison.  I am currently using this class to store the info:

```
public class myFSInfo
{
    public FileSystemInfo Dir;
    public string RelativePath;
    public string BaseDirectory;
    public myFSInfo(FileSystemInfo dir, string basedir)
    {
        Dir = dir;
        BaseDirectory = basedir;
        RelativePath = Dir.FullName.Substring(basedir.Length + (basedir.Last() == '\\' ? 1 : 2));
    }
    private myFSInfo() { }
    /// <summary>
    /// Copies a FileInfo or DirectoryInfo object to the specified path, creating folders and overwriting if necessary.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path"></param>
    public void CopyTo(string path)
    {
        if (Dir is FileInfo)
        {
            var f = (FileInfo)Dir;
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path.Substring(0,path.LastIndexOf("\\")));
            f.CopyTo(path,true);
        }
        else if (Dir is DirectoryInfo) Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }
}
```

I have tried XML and Binary serializing my class with no luck.  I have also tried creating a new class that does not contain the actual FileInfo but only selected attributes:

```
public class myFSModInfo
{
    public Type Type;
    public string BaseDirectory;
    public string RelativePath;
    public string FullName;
    public DateTime DateModified;
    public DateTime DateCreated;
    public myFSModInfo(FileSystemInfo dir, string basedir)
    {
        Type = dir.GetType();
        BaseDirectory = basedir;
        RelativePath = dir.FullName.Substring(basedir.Length + (basedir.Last() == '\\' ? 1 : 2));
        FullName = dir.FullName;
        DateModified = dir.LastWriteTime;
        DateCreated = dir.CreationTime;
    }
    private myFSModInfo() { }
    /// <summary>
    /// Copies a FileInfo or DirectoryInfo object to the specified path, creating folders and overwriting if necessary.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path"></param>
    public void CopyTo(string path)
    {
        if (Type == typeof(FileInfo))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf("\\")));
            File.Copy(FullName,path, true);
        }
        else if (Type == typeof(DirectoryInfo)) Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }
    public void Delete() 
    {
        if (Type == typeof(FileInfo)) File.Delete(FullName);
        else if (Type == typeof(DirectoryInfo)) Directory.Delete(FullName);
    }
}
```

I've also had no luck serializing this.  I could list the errors I've encountered with my various attempts, but it would probably be easier to select the best approach first.  Here is my serialization code:

```
public void SaveLog(string savepath, string dirpath)
    {
        var dirf = new myFSModInfo[1][];
        string[] patharr = {dirpath}; 
        GetFSInfo(patharr, dirf);

        var mySerializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(myFSModInfo[]));
        var myWriter = new StreamWriter(savepath);
        mySerializer.Serialize(myWriter, dirf[0]);
        myWriter.Close();

        /*var bf = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();   
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(savepath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);   
        bf.Serialize(fs, dirf[0]);  */
    }
```

Comment: Think you can only serialize properties, not variables.

Comment: Can you provide some more specific detail as to the problems you had?

Comment: did you declare the class as serializable?  [Serializable]

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thank you John.  Sorceri - I didn't do anything outside of the code I posted.  If declaring it as Serializable would fix my problem, can you let me know the syntax?  Octopoid - Most of the problems I enountered were failures of the serializer because a class didn't contain a 0-argument constructor.  I also had a problem with Type being protected variable.  If there's a specific route I should focus on, I can post exact error messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FileSystemInfo isn't serializable, because it is not a [simple type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691144%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). FileInfo isn't serializable, because it has no empty [default constructor](http://www.dotnetperls.com/default-constructor).

So if you want to save that information, you have to build your own class with simple types, that wrap that the information from FileInfo or FileSystemInfo.

```
[Serializable]
public class MyFileInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public long Length { get; set;}

    /// <summary>
    /// An empty ctor is needed for serialization.
    /// </summary>
    public MyFileInfo(){
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="test.MyFileInfo"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileInfo">File info.</param>
    public MyFileInfo(string path)
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo (path);
        this.Length = fileInfo.Length;
        this.Name = fileInfo.Name;
        // TODO: add and initilize other members
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
List<MyFileInfo> list = new List<MyFileInfo> ();

foreach (string entry in Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\temp"))
{
    list.Add (new MyFileInfo (entry));
}

XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<MyFileInfo>));
StringWriter sww = new StringWriter();
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww);
xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, list);

Console.WriteLine (sww.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you ec8or.  I realized after reading your response that I had mistakenly repeated the first code block, instead of posting my second class attempt.  I have now fixed that.  It's along the lines of what you suggest, but I'm getting this error: "System.InvalidOperationException: System.RuntimeType is inaccessible due to its protection level. Only public types can be processed."

Comment: Some access modifier is probably wrong. Make sure the class you want to serialize is public. If it got complex properties, they must have a publiv visible type, too. If you want to ignore some property, you have to use the [XmlIgnore] -Attribute.

Comment: You can see my class in the 2nd code block above.  I think I made both public.  I don't want to ignore any attribute, since I only included attributes I need in this class.  In my first class, I included a FileSystemInfo object, which has attributes I could ignore, but the XMLserializer doesn't like FileInfo.  I added the Serializeable tag, but still no luck.  Any idea what the issue is?

Comment: The problem here is ```Type```. It is not serializable, cause `System.RuntimeType is inaccessible due to its protection level.`. It is an interal CLR type. Additionaly it is not a simple Type. Got it?

Comment: So why do you need that Type? You could also create a bool property called IsFile as workarround!?

Comment: Do I need to encode the Type as a string?  What is the best way to go about saving the array?

Comment: That would work.  That's really the main reason I need it.  While I've done other coding, C# is new to me.  Is this the accepted way to go about saving data: create a class with the required properties, convert everything to simple types, and XML Serialize it?

Comment: Thats a way yes. THere is a big section in MSDN, that goes through all details. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Sorry, the chat is currently blocked at work.  I submitted a site review request, but for now I can't access it.  I couldn't find a way to send a PM either.

Comment: Maybe an alternative: Build md5 hashes of the files. Than you can check if anthing has changed later by comparing the hashes. There is no PM on SO.

Comment: So in the end i hope i could help you out. Please accept the answer if that was the case.

Comment: Chat is now unblocked.  I sent a message there.